# How to save information about selected mods?

Tags: civilization-5, mods

It's a problem one runs into when using **more than a few mods** in multitude of situations.

Let's say I play on two different computers regularly. The Steam Sync feature will take care of my saves, but I still have to remember which mods I selected for the particular game (because having selected not exactly the same exact mods will usually break saves).

Or let's say I just want to play several games on the same machine but each with different set of mods. I have to remember the exact set for each game (or write them down somewhere).

Is there a way to extract this info from some game file or is there maybe a mod that exports this somewhere in a convenient way?

Answer (score 3):

I found a pretty straightforward solution. When you fire up **the game menu** there's a little, inconspicuous text in the bottom left saying ***"Mods"***.

Like this:
[image]

Clicking it gives you a list of active mods. Now the only thing you have to do is making a screenshot like I did above (or probably at least two).

Comment: Yes, but how do you open this window when you can't load a save with mods that you don't remember?